# Last 3 values using foreach loop in php

Tags: php, foreach

I have a foreach loop. There has uncountable value. I want to print last 3 values.

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {

//print last 3 value.
}
```

Comment: "uncountable value" -- what does it mean?

Comment: "uncountable value" means that there has unlimited values.

Comment: @JakirHossain, you cannot get last 3 values from unlimited array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
  if (count($arr) - $i < 4)
    print($value);
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this you can use like this

```
$i = 0;
$len = count($array);
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        // first
    } else if ($i == $len - 3) {
        // last
    }
    else if ($i == $len - 2) {
        // last
    }
    else if ($i == $len - 1) {
        // last
    }
    // …
$i++;
}
```