# how to get last 3 items in foreach loop php

Tags: php, foreach

I want to get last 3 items of foreach loop of my code.

My code is :

```
foreach ($img as $spans) {

       $fimg = $spans ->getAttribute('loadlate');
       if ($spans ->getAttribute('class') === 'loadlate hidden ') {
       echo $fimg . '<br>';

}}
```

Example : my output will be :

```
111
222
333
444
555
```

I want to print just **333-444-555**

Comment: You can reverse the array and chop off anything after the first three items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last 3 values using foreach loop in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911624/last-3-values-using-foreach-loop-in-php)

Comment: Better still do the reverse sort amd limit in the database query that generates `$img`

Comment: for($i = count($img) - 1; $i > count($img) - 4;$ i--) {...}

Comment: `foreach (array_slice($img, -3) as $spans) {`

Comment: @Blake : would you explain more ? or example ?

Comment: @Sherif i do that but not working ! maybe i am wrong . would you send as an answer ?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob would you please all code as an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just slice off the last three and loop over that.

```
foreach (array_slice($img, -3) as $spans) { ...
```

---

On second thought, since it looks like you're iterating a `DomNodelist`, you can use its length to construct a `for` loop instead.

```
$len = $img->length;
$start = max($len - 3, 0);                      // calculate start index

for ($i=$start; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $spans = $img->item($i);                    // get the item at each index
    $fimg = $spans ->getAttribute('loadlate');
    if ($spans ->getAttribute('class') === 'loadlate hidden ') {
        echo $fimg . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in

Comment: Aha, I see. Is this part of a domdocument?

Comment: Oops, just noticed this was already suggested in the comments too.

Comment: @HamedAp Looks like I misunderstood what you were doing at first. I added another suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would just reverse the array and count

```
$img = array_reverse($img);
$i = 0;
foreach ($img as $spans) {
    $fimg = $spans ->getAttribute('loadlate');
    if ($spans ->getAttribute('class') === 'loadlate hidden ') {
        if(++$i>3) breal;
        echo $fimg . '<br>';

    }}
```

Comment: i dont see reverse ! are you sure ? you just add this :         if(++$i>3) break;